# C++ - Running code on Visual Studio 2015 / Two Errors C4552 '>>' operator has no effect; and expression must have constant value;

Tags: c++, visual-studio

The code below is showing two errors. They are the one belows:
C4552 '>>' operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect
expression must have constant value; expected operator with side-effect (related to the variable 'size'

The code is the one below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    int lectures[size][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cin >> lectures[i][0] >> lectures[i][1];
    }

    int n = sizeof(lectures) / sizeof(lectures[0]);

    int prefix_sum[size] = { 0 };


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        prefix_sum[lectures[i][0]]++;
        prefix_sum[lectures[i][1] + 1]--;
    }

    int ans = prefix_sum[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        prefix_sum[i] += prefix_sum[i - 1];
        ans = ans < prefix_sum[i] ? prefix_sum[i] : ans;
        
    }

    cout << ans;

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please help me to understand what is wrong here?
Any help is welcome!
Thank you! :)

Comment: `int lectures[size][2];` is a variable-length array, and C++ [doesn't have them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). Use `std::vector` instead. Same with `prefix_sum`.

Comment: And if you have the size of the arrays in `size`, why do you need `n`?

Comment: Could you indicate which line of your code is causing the error?

Comment: VLAs (see 1st comment) and remove `using namespace std;` as it's causing a clash between `size` and `std::size`. Have a read of [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)